# Rich Notifications Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

I want to subscribe for rich notifications using Microsoft graph API for calendar events. 
Below is the payload which I'm using to make subscription call :

```
{
    "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
    "notificationUrl": "https://notification.com/api/webhook",
    "resource": "Users('room_mailbox@abc.com')/events?$select=subject,start,end,organizer",
    "expirationDateTime": "2018-12-06T18:23:45.9356913Z",
    "clientState": "secretClientValue"
}
```

the response I get is:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "IncludeProperties flag should be true in payload to support rich notifications.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "b281f496-6121-40d0-9f48-452922170598",
        "date": "2018-12-06T09:32:46"
    }
}
```

}

Using the payload :

```
{
    "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
    "notificationUrl": "https://notification.com/api/webhook",
    "resource": "Users('room_mailbox@abc.com')/events,
    "expirationDateTime": "2018-12-06T18:23:45.9356913Z",
    "clientState": "secretClientValue", 
    "includeProperties" : true
}
```

I successfully created the subscription but got default data in notifications.

I have used rich notifications using outlook v2 API. But can't find any documentation regarding Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: I don't follow. Why did you drop the `$select=subject,start,end,organizer` when you added `includeProperties: true`?

Answer (score 2):

Rich Notifications are not yet supported for Calendar events through Microsoft Graph.

We will improve the error message.

Comment: Error message is improved now :  We mention that the rich notifications are not supported for the Exchange yet.

Comment: Any update on rich notifications support in microsoft graph subscriptions?

Comment: I'm guessing never @VenkatChepuru ?